# Compact objects in Ind-categories

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Assume a category $\mathcal{D}$ admits small filtrant inductive limits. Then call an object $Y$ of $\mathcal{D}$ *compact*, if $\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(Y,\cdot )$ commutes with these small filtrant inductive limits (i found this definition in the book "Categories and Sheaves" of M. Kashiwara and P. Schapira where this property is called *finite presentation*).

Now my question is:

> Denoting by $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ the full subcategory of Ind-objects in $\mathrm{Func}(\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set})$ and by $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})^c$ the compact objects of $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$, which requirements must $\mathcal{C}$ meet to make the canonical functor $$\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})^c\tag{1}$$ (given by the Yoneda embedding) an equivalence of categories?

In some exercise (I think it was exercise 6.1) of the above cited book I found for example the claim that if $\mathcal{C}$ is any small category, an object $A$ of $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ is compact if and only if there is an object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, together with morphisms $$A\overset{f}{\rightarrow}X\overset{g}{\rightarrow}A$$ in $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ such that $g\circ f$ is the identity, and that hence if (and actually only if) $\mathcal{C}$ is idempotent complete, (1) is indeed an equivalence, but unfortunately I don't see why any compact object $A$ admits $X$, $f$ and $g$ as described above (the converse is rather clear). Could anyone give me a hint? And can the smallness condition on $\mathcal{C}$ be weakened or modified?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smallness condition is not especially important. The key condition is indeed idempotent-completeness.

Suppose $A$ is a compact object in $\mathbf{Ind} (\mathcal{C})$. By definition, there is a filtered diagram $Y : \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ such that $A$ is the colimit of $Y$ in $\mathbf{Ind} (\mathcal{C})$. But the canonical comparison map
$$\varinjlim \mathrm{Hom} (A, Y) \to \mathrm{Hom} (A, \varinjlim Y)$$
is a bijection, and $\varinjlim Y \cong A$, so there is some object $j$ in $\mathcal{J}$ and some morphism $f : A \to Y j$ in $\mathbf{Ind} (\mathcal{C})$ such that $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$, where $g : Y j \to A$ is the component of the colimiting cocone. In particular, if $\mathcal{C}$ is idempotent-complete, then $A$ is isomorphic to some object in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!